# how to log errors and map the error to the source in ionic 3 without ionic pro and with ionic pro

Tags: ionic-framework, error-handling, ionic3, stack-trace

Does anybody know how to stack trace the error logs and maps the errors to source without ionic pro. Or anybody can post a sample showing the use of ionic error monitoring and logs stack trace